# MPPT charger - where to learn more

Tags: power-electronics, repair

I would like to learn more about the design of MPPT chargers so that I can repair them.

I can repair various electronics (e.g. SMPS, chargers, cell phones, etc.) but not MPPT chargers yet. Where can I find good resources?

Answer (score 1):

A solar MPPT battery charger, will contain a DC-DC converter, measurement, and control circuits. Usually the control uses a microcontroller or digital logic. The DC-DC topology can be as simple as a two-switch buck converter.

If you are familiar with SMPS topology and repair, I assume you have some refrences for these already. You may start with understanding how solar cells behave as a source, for example https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/solar-cell-operation/iv-curve (from Arizona State University).